# Graph points between ticks - crosshair height equal with the point y

Tags: javascript, highcharts

1. Is it posible to display graph points between ticks to represent a duration period?
2. Is crosshair, in x axis, able to have custom height according to the y of the graph's point.
3. Can tick step:2 to begin with empty value?

Expectation:

[image: expectation]

Reality:

[fiddle.jshell.net/ssbeefeater/fx5d8wvk/](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ssbeefeater/fx5d8wvk)

Comment: 1. Set tickmarkPlacement to 'between' https://fiddle.jshell.net/fx5d8wvk/8/
2. You can use labels.formatter or tickPositioner to have complete control over labels and ticks http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter